# Create a graph accumulating data over time - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, accumulate

I want to create a graph, for example "number of accumulative likes over time" in ruby on rails. I need to do something like get the base likes:

```
base_likes = Like.find :all, :conditions => ["created_at < ?", from_date]
```

And get the number of likes per day in array:

```
[3, 0, 10, 12, 0, 24]
```

And then loop through the number likes per day including the base likes to get an array like:

```
[3, 3, 13, 25, 25, 49]
```

I wondered if there was a magic ruby way?!

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve information from the db, I'd head first to:

```
hash = Like.count(:group => "date(created_at)")
```

But this will provide only days where here have been likes so it could be a pain to fill in the gaps.

Otherwise, [looking here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043388/getting-count-of-elements-by-created-at-by-day-in-a-given-month), you could create your array of likes per day.

Then to get the cumulative likes, I'd do:

```
ary = [3, 0, 10, 12, 0, 24]
ary.each_with_index.map {|e,i| ary[0..i].inject(&:+)}
```

Comment: seems @Alex already has an array with zeros. Wouldn't it be simpler to do `x=0 ; ary.map {|i| x += i }` ?