# Counting User registration for a day, week, month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to count the users that registered on the website on specific periods.
For example:

Today: 5

Yesterday: 7

Over last week: 28

Over last month: 101

I used this [stackoveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043388/getting-count-of-elements-by-created-at-by-day-in-a-given-month) that is somewhat relevant to what I want to do. But when I try to apply it it has several problems in terms of logic for what I try to do.

So what I figured out is that I should use something like:

```
@lastfivedays = User.where(
'created_at >= :five_days_ago',
:five_days_ago => Time.now - 5.days,
)
```

But where am I placing this and how do I use it in the view?
Yes I am lost on how I do something like this in Rails as I am new to this. Any guidance, tip will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should go in the controller and you can then access the instance variable in the view.

Controller:

```
@lastfivedays = User.where(
  'created_at >= :five_days_ago',
  :five_days_ago => 5.days.ago,
).count
```

View:

```
Number of users who registered in last 5 days: <%= @lastfivedays %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [ActiveRecord Scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

You could have something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...

  scope :joined_within_five_days, -> { where('created_at >= :five_days_ago',
:five_days_ago => Time.now - 5.days,) }

...
end
```

Your controller could then use the approriate one. For example

```
@users = User.joined_within_five_days
```